# Create longer numbers by stringing together database integer fields

Tags: mysql

I have fields in my database table as such: r1,r2,g1,g2,b1,b2

I want to link these items together within the MySQL query in order to turn these fields into numbers.  So, instead of returning separate r1, g1 and b1, it will return the 3 items strung together with no spaces or commas making what appears to be a single number.

Like this: (I am using dots to show that they are connected):

```
 r1 . g1 . b1 , r2 . g2 . b2
```

So, as an example if the items stored in the database were:

```
r1 = 7
r2 = 8


g1 = 12
g2 = 13


b1 = 17
b2 = 18
```

Upon executing the query, I would get this result:

```
 71217,81318
```

I am thinking using CONCAT_WS in some way is how this should be done, but I am just not sure how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

`CONCAT()` should be sufficient for this

```
select concat(r1 , g1 , b1) as N1 , CONCAT(r2 , g2 , b2 ) as N2 from whatever
```

<kbd>[See a SQLfiddle for this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09032/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Use concat in select like below (May be this helpful to you):

i am considering you have table t1 and my query is like below

```
select concat(r1,g1,b1) as no1,concat(r2,g2,b2) as no2 from t1
```

Note : If any issue let me know

Answer (score 0):

After posting, I was able to come up with the answer to this:

```
SELECT ID, CONCAT_WS(',', CONCAT(r1,g1,b1),CONCAT(r2,g2,b2),CONCAT(r3,g3,b3),CONCAT(r4,g4,b4),CONCAT(r5,g5,b5)) AS color FROM mytable;
```

However, I welcome any suggestions or additional answers.

Comment: Or single concat: `SELECT CONCAT(r1, g1, b1, ',', r2, g2, b2) as color FROM mytable`